# Write the Fourier series to $f(t)=|\sin t|$

Tags: fourier-series

I have this function which I should write the Fourier series for: $f(t)=|\sin t|$

I now that the period is $\pi$ and that it is an even function. Because it is even, I only need to calculate the cos coefficient which is:

$$a_n = \frac{2}{T}\int_0^T f(t)\cos(n\omega t)dt = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin t| \cos(n\omega t)dt$$

My problem here is that I do not know how to handle the abs sign affecting sin. If it has just been $\sin t \cos (n\omega t)$ then I could use the formula $$ \sin\alpha\cos\beta=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha -\beta)+\sin(\alpha+\beta))$$ but I don't know if I could do that now... How should I solve this?

Comment: There's no nicer way than to split up the integral into the different parts where $\sin t$ is positive and negative.

Comment: But how will that affect the result?

Comment: I would say, for $t \in \langle 0,\pi \rangle $ is $\sin t >= 0$, so 
$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin t| \cos(n\omega t)dt=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin t \cos(n\omega t)dt$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $t\in[0,\pi]$, then $\sin t$ is non-negative. Consequently, we can directly use the formula 
$$\sin\alpha\cos\beta=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha -\beta)+\sin(\alpha+\beta)).$$